# Necessary and sufficient conditions for a morphism of real affine varieties to have a closed image

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $\phi : X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of affine varieties over $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\phi^*$ be the pullback on coordinate rings
$\phi^* : O_Y \rightarrow O_X$. If $\phi^*$ is  surjecitve, then $\phi(X) \subset Y$ is closed. This is in
[answer to: surjectivity of induced map implies that a morphism has closed image](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71623/why-does-surjectivity-of-the-induced-map-show-that-a-morphism-of-affine-varietie).
Is there a necessary and sufficient condition, or if not, then a necessary condition on $\phi^*$  for a closed image $\phi(X)$?

Comment: Why have you included "real" here? Are you asking about the closure of the image of the real points in the standard topology, or are you working scheme-theoretically?

Comment: "real" because the field over which the polynomials are given is $\mathbb{R}$. The closure is in  Zariski topology, scheme theoretic.